# Evitar string "px" al animar opacidad JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animación

Existe alguna manera simple de evitar sumar el string "px" cuando no se necesita?
He tenido problemas al resolverlo con un operador ternario.
Mi idea es eliminar el postfijo "px" para casos como "opacity" pero tenerlo disponible por ejemplo para casos con "width" o "top".
Aquí un [ejemplo funcional del código](https://jsfiddle.net/nazimba/qzsh6jfm/4/) y una cita o extracto de la linea que deseo mejorar:

```
// ...
// postfix = p == "opacity" ? "" : "px";
// ...
// this.node.style[p] = rate * (this.end - this.start) + this.start + postfix;
// ...
```

Aqui un recorte de imagen para el que no encuentra la linea de codigo a corregir.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega por favor el código aquí

Comment: Hola BetaM, he colocado el link con el codigo funcionando en el comentario, aqui va de todos modos: https://jsfiddle.net/nazimba/xavzbjmy/6/

Comment: De donde sale postfix en tu código? (ya ví el código entero, pero no se de donde sale).

Comment: Hola Riven, en el jsfiddle. Aqui solo hice una cita del mismo. Este sitio en español es malisimo. En la version en ingles ya hubiera tenido 20 respuestas. Me dieron de baja para hacer preguntas por borrar dos consultas sin saber lo malo que era para las reglas de stackoverflow.

Comment: @Riven, he subido un recorte para que puedas encontrar el fragmento de codigo a corregir. Gracias!

Comment: Perdona el retraso, no habia visto el igual que marcaba el valor de postfix xd.

Comment: Amigo, tu código funciona correctamente según lo que deseas, lo ejecute en el navegador me puse a inspeccionar y solo se esta sumando el string "px" donde se requiere, es decir en la medida top, pero no se esta agregando en opacity, que es justo lo que necesitas.

Comment: @Riven, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para verlo. Es cierto, el código funciona aunque da error en ciertas animaciones mas complejas y no puedo entender todavía porque. Mi idea era encontrar otras maneras de resolver la situación, quizás sin la asignación ternaria que utilice inicialmente.